# To cd into a directory

Tags: permissions

What permissions are needed? I mean the minimum permission needed to actually cd into a directory.

It's just a general question I have. If someone has executable permissions is that enough to be able to access a directory via the CD command? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

x - execute - permission needed to `cd` into the directory.

r - read - permission needed to do a `ls` inside the directory.

w - write - permissions needed to create a new file (or sub-directory) inside the directory.

Comment: you can create a new user and test it yourself. Create a new user by this command, `sudo adduser newuser10`, then you can switch between users with `su - <user name>` command. Now you can create a directory in one user, give it different permissions, switch to another user, and check what can changes are there. Assuming you can use `sudo` command.